# How to restructure objects of data into arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I currently have 1 array that has 6 names of the category and 6 arrays of objects, each of which includes 5 objects for each category. What's the best way to restructure the 1-category array and 6-arrays of objects so that I can get just 6 arrays of objects contain both data from the array.

```js
let categoryArray = ["a", "b", "c","d","e","f"];
let outcomeArrays = [
    [ {p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null} ],
    [ {p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null} ],
    [ {p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null} ],
    [ {p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null} ],
    [ {p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null} ],
    [ {p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null} ]
];
```

What I want is to make an array that has such a structure like below:

```js
[{category: "a", 
details: [{p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}]},
{category: "b",
details: [{p:11,q:22,r:null},{p:33,q:44,r:null},{p:55,q:66,r:null},{p:77,q:88,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}]},
...
]
```

I tried to use push and map method. It didn't work. I even tried to use lodash and can't find a method dealing with this situation.

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version from @thoughtsunificator looks right.

This is a variation using Array.map:

```
let categoryArray = ["a", "b", "c","d","e","f"];
let outcomeArray = [[{p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}],
[{p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}],
[{p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}],
[{p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}],
[{p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}],
[{p:1,q:2,r:null},{p:3,q:4,r:null},{p:5,q:6,r:null},{p:7,q:8,r:null},{p:9,q:10,r:null}],];

const categories = categoryArray.map((cat, index) => ({
  category: cat,
  details: outcomeArray[index]
}));
console.log(categories);
```

Comment: I don’t understand your comments. There isn’t an explicit for loop in this code. Are you asking a new question?

Comment: I fixed it. Now it works. I put it inside of a loop that caused looping categories array for 6 times.